# Control object location with keyboard

Tags: camera

Would there be a way to control a blender object and maintain realistic movement like you would moving a character in a third person game? Keyframes look very unnatural for what i'm making.
edit:to be more specific, I just need something to *simulate human controller movement*. keyframes look like, well, keyframes.

Comment: It sounds as if you need the old Game Engine which is no longer part of Blender. try asking [here](https://upbge.org/#/community).

Comment: I am aware of the blender game engine. I was talking about something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ng7E10a1brc&ab_channel=ScanningCars) but with a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

While in camera viewport, press shift+~ (tilde key) then tab key to activate gravity. Now you can use WSAD keys to control camera movement, very similar to a character in a third person game what you mentioned.

Comment: I originally thought of this but didn't use it because it did not set the position, but after further easerch, I realised I can set an object as a camera and navigate it, which works. Thanks!

Comment: update: I found out that this is an improvement, but still looks somewhat unnatural. you see, a human hand has very small and precise movements, which is why first person looks natural. However for a controller or a top-down game, the machine does not interpret your finger as doing precise movements. It sees 4 buttons being pressed (wasd) not relative to a mouse position.

**tldr:** first person uses your mouse which makes it look unnatural, and locking the mouse makes it so that you cant see anything around yourself.